# How to move the text to the left inside a div?

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a template for a personal web page. I would like to use the space in the div #content that is to the left, but I can't figure out what to do to move the text to the left without moving the sidebar div either to the bottom or somewhere else. This is the CSS code:

```
#content {
  float: right;
  width: 605px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 170px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  float: left;
}
```

I have attached an image, which you can see in the link (I still don't have enough points to load it here). The texts inside the div are inside a "p".

[image: image of the template]

This is the HTML code for the content and sidebar:

```
    <div id="content">
        <h2>Introduction</h2>
        <p>Welcome to exalted, a free valid CSS &amp; XHTML strict web template from <a href="http://www.spyka.net" title="spyka webmaster">spyka Webmaster</a>. 
            This template is <strong>free</strong> to use permitting a link remains back to  <a href="http://www.spyka.net" title="spyka webmaster">http://www.spyka.net</a>. 
            Should you wish to use this template unbranded you can buy a template license from our website for 5.00 GBP, this will allow you remove all branding related to our site, 
            for more information about this see below.</p>  

        <p>This template has been tested in:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Firefox 3.5</li>
            <li>Opera 10.00</li>
            <li>IE 7 and 8</li>
            <li>Chrome</li>
        </ul>

        <h3>Buy unbranded</h3>
        <p>Purchasing a template license for 5.00 GBP (at time of writing around 7.40 USD) gives you the right to remove any branding including links, logos and source tags relating to spyka webmaster. Payments are processed using paypal, with which we are a verified member, via the licensing page on our website which can be accessed at <a href="http://www.spyka.net/licensing" title="template license">http://www.spyka.net/licensing</a></p>

        <h3>More free web templates</h3>
        <p>Looking for more free web templates for other projects? Check out our <a href="http://justfreetemplates.com/portfolio?user=spyka">free web template portfolio</a>. We also offer <a href="http://www.spyka.net/wordpress-themes">WordPress themes</a> and <a href="http://www.awesomestyles.com">phpBB3 styles</a>, all of which are released under Open Source or Creative Commons licenses!</p>

        <h3>Webmaster forums</h3>   
        <p>You can get help with editing and using this template, as well as design tips, tricks and advice in our <a href="http://www.spyka.net/forums" title="webmaster forums">webmaster forums</a></p>

    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>    
           <li>
                <h4><span>Navigate</span></h4>
                <ul class="blocklist">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="examples.html">Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul> 
    </div>
```

Comment: Why do you have a padding left of 170px on the content?

Comment: Try setting the padding-left to 0 on the p

Comment: That is how the template is designed. I am not a designer, but just trying to understand how this work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the

```
padding-left: 170px;
```

In this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rb987nL7/11/) I changed the padding-left to 0 and re-arranged the #sidebar div above the #content div. and made them both

```
float: left;
```

I hope this helps your issue. Use of bootstrap would be very useful here in my opinion, but I don't know if you are allowed to use it in your situation.

Comment: I am using AJAX. I will test with your answer.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin. You shared some light to the solution. I used your technique with this variant of your suggestion and it worked fine for me:

#content {
float: right;
width: 710px;
margin: 0px;
padding-left: 15px;
border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sidebar {
 width: 200px;
 padding-left: 1px;
 float: left;

}

Comment: No problem @Mr.Munoz, glad I could help in some way. Good luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to align text to the left in a div, you can use `text-align: left`. Although, text is aligned to the left by default.

Per your specific case, you may find [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to be useful.

With the addition of a parent container (`main`), the only CSS you will need is as follows:

```
main {
  display: flex;
}

#content {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
  flex: 1;
}
```

I also switched the order of the `.sidebar` and `#content` elements to not be backwards.

Here is a demo http://codepen.io/JKudla/pen/yMxXYZ?editors=1100

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, @Kudla69. This is new to me. I will check on it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves the problem:

```
#content {
float: right;
width: 710px;
margin: 0px;
padding-left: 15px;
border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    float: left;

}
```

[solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpCgH.png)

Thanks to Kevin for helping.